# Electron. How show progress of installation update

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I need to create window which show the progress of installation update for my electron application like in discord application.
I've already create window which show the progress of download, but I need to show the progress of installation update too.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

For showing the installer progress event you can use "nsis" key in your package.json file. Add the following code to your package.json file:

```
"nsis": { 
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true, 
    "createDesktopShortcut": true,
    "oneClick": false
}
```

Here `oneClick: false` does the magic. It tells whether to create one-click installer or assisted. By default the value is true, you can set the value to false to show a guided installation process.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using the official `autoUpdater` module; Is not providing any events on the update/download progress.

However, there are alternatives to this module such as

- [`electron-updater`](https://www.electron.build/auto-update#event-download-progress) : *If your are building with `elctron-builder`*
- [`update-electron-app`](https://github.com/electron/update-electron-app): If you are deploying on Github you can look at

In any case, your application must be signed.

Electron off doc : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/updates